# ReasonML cycle dependency

Tags: module, dependencies, ocaml, reason, bucklescript

I'm working on a bucklescript binding to leafletjs based on [this project](https://github.com/reasonml-community/bs-leaflet) .

With leaflet a Map has a function to add layer and a Layer has a function to add itself to a map.

This is what I would like to achieve with ReasonML :

```
module Map = {
    type t;
    [@bs.send] external addLayer : (t, Layer.t) => t = "addLayer";
};

module Layer = {
    type t;
    [@bs.send] external addTo : Map.t => unit = "addTo";
};
```

Unfortunately I get an **unbound module Layer** error.

How do I make the compiler aware of the type described after ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Option 1: Define the types in a common module and alias them:

```rust
type map;
type layer;

module Map = {
    type t = map;
    [@bs.send] external addLayer : (t, layer) => t = "addLayer";
};

module Layer = {
    type t = layer;
    [@bs.send] external addTo : map => unit = "addTo";
};
```

Option 2: Make the modules mutually recursive:

```rust
module rec Map : {
    type t;
    [@bs.send] external addLayer : (t, Layer.t) => t = "addLayer";
} = {
    type t;
    [@bs.send] external addLayer : (t, Layer.t) => t = "addLayer";
}

and  Layer : {
    type t;
    [@bs.send] external addTo : Map.t => unit = "addTo";
} = {
    type t;
    [@bs.send] external addTo : Map.t => unit = "addTo";
};
```

Comment: @Yvain - cool shortcut–if the modules are recursive and just define types and externals you can just make them refer to themselves: `module rec Map: {...} = Map and Layer: {...} = Layer;`